# Is it possible to downgrade Jenkins container plugin thought CLI?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I have a job that creates a container from Jenkins image. I would like to add to the script one more option:
Currently, it's installing the image with DSL plugin version 1.77. is there a command I can run from CLI to downgrade the plugin version to 1.57?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Config as Code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/README.md) for installing plugins.

If you're using the jenkins image, just use an older version of the image that has the proper plugin version